Issues adding GA4 User Key Event Rate Looker Studio when using Groups
I am working in Looker Studio to create a basic pivot table for website user conversion rates.
When adding groups, my UserKeyEventRate is inaccurate.
I created a group based on Landing Page + Query String dimension. When I use the group as a row, column, or filter in my pivot table my UserKeyEventRate becomes inaccurate.
Since I created my new grouping with:

Group 1) Anyone that contains "X" in Landing Page + Query String
Group 2) Everyone Else

Shouldn't the UserKeyEventRate still be accurate?
Are there any recommendations to fix the UserKeyEventRate
(or)
create a new calculated field showing: Unique Users That Reached Key Event/ Unique Users
